# Error with django starting

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am working on [pycharm](/questions/tagged/pycharm), with a [django](/questions/tagged/django) project.
Whenever I do the "run" thing, and I go to my home page or wherever " http://127.0.0.1:8000/.."
Everything works fine, but I get this error :

> C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py:126:
>   RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.core.context_processors is
>   deprecated in favor of django.template.context_processors.   return
>   _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Should I change the django version or what ?!
Thanks.

settings.py file :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Please provide the Django version number. It is advisable to use the last stable release. Probably you are running an example that uses code that was meant for a version previous to 1.10, current stable is 1.11 LTS

Comment: django version 1.9.4

Comment: You only needed to post your `TEMPLATES` setting to show your context processors. As the warning says, you shouldn't post your `SECRET_KEY` in public. You should change it now.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not an error but a warning.
2. It says some functions are not available (are deprecated) in next django versions, so you should keep in mind that if you are planning to upgrade.
   That's it.

Comment: I agree. And this is a fairly generic warning. Here is more info on Django's templating system: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

Answer (score 1):

The warning is suggesting that you update your context processors in your settings to use `django.template.context_processors` instead of `django.core.context_processors`.

In your case, it is the `request` processor (the first item) that is causing the warning. You already have the new path `django.template.context_processors.request` in the list, so just remove `django.core.context_processors.request`. Your context processors will then be:

```
'context_processors': [
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
```

If you need more specific instruction like that, then please edit your question to include your list of context processors from your settings file.

Comment: I added the settings file

Answer (score 0):

I think Context Processors used to be listed in their own tuple arrangement in the settings.py in earlier versions of django but this was changed and eventually deprecated in Dango 1.10 hence the RemovedInDjango110Warning.

Now you should list your context processors as options within the Templates setting of your settings.py file.  Something that looks a little like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
         'BACKEND': '.......',
         'DIRS': '........',

         'OPTIONS':{
             'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request', 
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
             ] 
         },
     },
]
```

The startproject command in later versions should actually set this up for you.